# What is the time complexity of these 3 loops?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, big-o

What is the time complexity of this code?

```
let time = 0;
for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
  for(let j = 1; j <= i; j++)
  {
    for(let k = 1; k <= n*n; k += i*i)
    {
      time++
    }
  }
}
```

Is the innermost loop `O(1)` or `O(n^2)`?

Comment: @EdHeal The second loop isn't up to `n`, it is up to `i`, thus it is less than O(N^4) but more than O(N^3)

Comment: The innermost loop is `O(n^2)`, but that is not the same question as in your title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is `O(N^2logN)`.

Analysis:

For a constant `i`, the innermost loop will be executed for about `(N*N)/(i*i)` times. The second loop will be executed for `i` times. So `time++` will be executed for about `((N*N)/(i*i))*i = (N*N)/i` times.

So the total expense will be the sum for every `i`.
`(N*N)*(1/1+1/2+1/3....1/N) ≈ N^2logN` is your answer.